# Applying jQuery function to one div class with randomly given numbers?

Tags: jquery

I have a several scrollable menus at one page. There is a jQuery function which handles all those menus in "menu per menu" fashion, after I type this (hardcoded as it is) in a .js file:

```
    $(function(){
             Scrollable(".menu_wrapper1");
             Scrollable(".menu_wrapper2");

..and so on, all up to... 

       Scrollable(".menu_wrapper9");
```

HTML is simple as this..

```
    <div class="menu_wrapper1">Menu data</div>
    <div class="menu_wrapper2">Menu data 2</div>

and so on, up to 9 again.
```

Anyway, there is some possibility in near future for those menus to be more then 9 at one page or with different numbers at the end (like `"menu_wrapper17"`) for example), so any chance for those different numbers of classes to be recognized and applied to this function by jQuery itself?

Something like `Scrollable(".menu_wrapper[*]");` or similar I guess so function can be applied to any number?

Thx!

**EDIT:** Please, beware that every class has its own controls given by function.

Comment: Can't you select them differently with Scrollable("#big_menu_wrapper > div")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("div[class^='menu_wrapper']").each(function () {
Scrollable("."+$(this).attr('class'));
});
```

This will get each div whose classname startswith 'menuwarpper' and calls the Scrollable() with its class name as parameter.

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: I guess this is what you need

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to add another class, such as `scrollable_wrapper`, and select that:

```
<div class="scrollable_wrapper menu_wrapper2">...</div>
```

```
Scrollable('.scrollable_wrapper');
```

Comment: Please check my edit. Every class has its own controls given by function (scrolling and stopping at some point, I mean menus are separated). Can this work in that fashion?

Comment: @Xfile, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "has its own controls given by function", but if whatever generates that HTML code can also add another class along with the `menu_wrapperN` class, then yes, it should work.

Comment: I certainly believe that this solution is cleaner than the accepted solution. It incapsulates shared functionality in one classname and is much less susceptible to break when changes are made to unrelated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions here:

1) Wrap all your menu_wrapper:

```
  <div id="big_menu_wrapper ">
    <div class="menu_wrapper1">Menu data</div>
    <div class="menu_wrapper2">Menu data 2</div>
  </div>
```

and select with `Scrollable("#big_menu_wrapper > div")`

2) Add the same class to all your menu_wrapper :

```
  <div class="menu_wrapper menu_wrapper1">Menu data</div>
  <div class="menu_wrapper menu_wrapper2">Menu data 2</div>
```

and select with `Scrollable(".menu_wrapper")`

3) Refactor your javascript function